# how to read PDF from in memory uploaded file python 3.6

Tags: django, pdf, python-3.6

I am trying to read a PDF file , i am uploading it using the following code:

```
    for file in request.FILES.getlist('the_file') :
        fp=tempfile.TemporaryFile()
        uploadedFile=file
```

I understand the PyPDF2 doesn't support  in memory uploaded file ,

tried several solutions i saw ,but couldn't solve the problem.

Will appreciate any help.

Thanks,

Nir

Comment: Have you tried `pdf =  PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(file.read())`

Comment: I am getting, AttributeError("'bytes' object has no attribute 'seek'",)

Comment: `import io` `pdf = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(io.BytesIO(file.read()))` should work.